# Struggling with JS websocket

Tags: javascript, websocket

I want to send the following websocket:

Index.html:

```
<script>
    websocket = new WebSocket('wss://websocketurl', 'xmpp');
    websocket.send('<message to="somevalue" type="somevalue" xmlns="somevalue"><body>Foo</body><nick xmlns="http://someurl">Foo1</nick></message>')
</script>
```

But when I go to index.html, I get the following

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aqojm.png)

Also, there seems not to be an escaping quotes issue

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is that the actual code? My guess is no.

Comment: Yeah, that's only it. Just some other values than the ones i set as foo or somevalue

Answer (score -1):

From this code you've shared it doesn't look like you're connecting to a server or setting events to listen for responses?

You might try something like this -

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    // const websocket = new WebSocket('wss://websocketurl', 'xmpp');
    // websocket.send(`<message to="somevalue" type="somevalue" xmlns="somevalue"><body>Foo</body><nick xmlns="http://someurl">Foo1</nick></message>`)
    function WebSocket() {
        if ("WebSocket" in window) {
            alert("WebSocket is supported by your Browser!");

            var ws = new WebSocket('wss://websocketurl', 'xmpp');//This would be the route to your server

            ws.onopen = () => { //once the connection is open you can send a message
                ws.send("Message to send");
                alert("Message is sent...");
            };

            ws.onmessage = (e) => { //listens for the event from the server
                var _msg = e.data;
                alert("Message is received...");
            }

            ws.onclose = () => {
                alert("Connection is closed...");
            };
        }
        else {
            alert("WebSocket Not Supported by your browser!");
        }
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="sse">
    <a href="javascript:WebSocket()">Run WebSocket</a>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Let me know if this helps or if I'm wildly off base here.

Comment: You mean like this: 
```
<script>
    websocket = new WebSocket('wss://websocketurl', 'xmpp');
    websocket.send(`<message to="somevalue" type="somevalue" xmlns="somevalue"><body>Foo</body><nick xmlns="http://someurl">Foo1</nick></message>`)
</script>
```

If so, didn't work :/

Comment: I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`

Comment: No, just around the string you're passing into the send method. Also can you share the rest of the code so that I can try to recreate it on my end?

Answer (score -1):

I found out this was a problem with Live-HTTP-Server VS code extension, which displayed incorrectly HTML and javascript. I opened the page using another server, then it worked